# laraver запрос связанной модели select и paginate

Tags: laravel, pagination

всем привет, laravel 5.5
Есть модель теги, и он связан к модели post через belongsToMany, итак в контроллере:

```
$tag = Tag::select('id', 'title', 'slug')->whereSlug($slug)->first();
$posts = $tag->posts()->select('posts.id', 'title_en as title', 'description_en as description', 'posts.slug', 'posts.image', 'posts.views', 'posts.count_comments', 'posts.translate')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(12));
```

При этом запросе формируется такой SQL запрос

```
select `posts`.`id`, `title_en` as `title`, `description_en` as `description`, `posts`.`slug`, `posts`.`image`, `posts`.`views`, `posts`.`count_comments`, `posts`.`translate`, `posts`.*, `post_tags`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id`, `post_tags`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id` from `posts` inner join `post_tags` on `posts`.`id` = `post_tags`.`post_id` where `post_tags`.`tag_id` = 422 order by `id` desc limit 12 offset 0
```

получается при вызове пагинации добавляется запись в select **`posts`.*** что и отменяет все предыдущие select. Если вместо pagination() использовать get() то все норм, но нужна пагинация со всеми методами, как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так:

```
$posts = \DB::table('posts')
    ->join('post_tags', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_tags.post_id')
    ->where('post_tags.tag_id', '=', $tag->id)
    ->select('posts.id', $title, $description, 'posts.slug', 'posts.image', 'posts.views', 'posts.count_comments', 'posts.translate')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(20);
```